# how to get token from 1 api and pass the token to authentication of another api in azure api gateway

Tags: azure-api-management, api-gateway

I have 2 APIs in azure API gateway.

1. Generates a token from 1 API.
2. Use that token in authentication in another API

How can I combine the above APIs into 1 or connect both in 1 flow?

Note: Both the APIs are on different servers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the backend url is different, its better to configure as two APIs.

Please follow the steps below.

1. Create Auth API and set the auth server as backend url
2. Create your API which consumes and set the backendurl.
3. Create a product which links these 2 apis. (So the subscription key will be same for the both apis.)
4. The user can call the auth url and get the token
5. Add it as a header to the next api.

If you only want to configure single api, follow below steps.

1. Create the api with auth endpoint in it.
2. Use the `<set-backend-service/>` for the auth url to set the differnt backend server.
   see more on  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#SetBackendService
3. create a product with single api

Here the url prefix will be same and functionality will be working as expected.